# Monitor Azure API Management Response time in Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-api-management

We have multiple APIs in Azure API Management Service. I can see individual API metrics in APIM Analytics. How can I integrate this to Grafana to monitor individual API response time.

Answer (score 0):

All metrics from APIM are published to [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview) for which there is a [data source plugin for Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource).

With the plugin configured, you can build dashboards using the data from Azure Monitor.

There is an [official doc for using Grafana with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/grafana-plugin) which explains this in detail.